# JRebel: ERROR javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: jrebel

idea 2017.1，tomcat9.0.0.M20，jrebel7.0.8. Run with jrebel for "Tomcat 9.0.0.M20"

HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/jasper/compiler/JspUtil.getInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/tomcat/Jar;Lorg/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext;)Ljava/io/BufferedInputStream; @35: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/io/InputStream' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/io/BufferedInputStream' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @35
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/tomcat/Jar', 'org/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext', 'java/io/InputStream' }
    stack: { 'java/io/InputStream' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b01 b803 a299 001f 2cb6 0368 b803 6e2b
    0x0000010: b903 7201 002a b603 754e 2d01 b803 a299
    0x0000020: 0005 2db0 014e 2bc6 001a 2a04 2ab6 0002
    0x0000030: b600 083a 042b 1904 b900 b802 004e a700
    0x0000040: 092c 2ab6 00b9 4e2d c700 17bb 00ba 5912
    0x0000050: bb2a b800 bcb7 00bd b803 a8c0 03aa bfbb
    0x0000060: 00be 592d 1104 00b7 00bf b0
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@36)
    append_frame(@65,Null)
    full_frame(@71,{Object[#16],Object[#650],Object[#652],Object[#421]},{})
    same_frame(@95)

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:338)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
com.darlingtech.util.SessionFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionFilter.java:65)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:123)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: Confirmed bug in integration with tomcat 9.0.0.M18 and later. Will let you know when it's fixed.

Comment: Try the latest nightly: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/nightly-build
It should work with tomcat versions up to 9.0.0.M20

Answer (score 2):

Integration with Tomcat 9.0.0.M20 has been added in the 7.0.9 version of JRebel.